Proving the monotonicity and unimodality of 2 functions
We have the following optimization problem
\begin{align*}
\max_{z\in[0,1/2]}~f(z;t)=\frac{(4\alpha z^3-6\alpha z^2+3\alpha z-3\alpha+3)t^3-6z(1-\alpha)t^2+3z^2(1-\alpha)t-\alpha z^3}{6t^3},
\end{align*}
where $t\geq 1$ and $\alpha\in[0,1]$.
The optimal solution is:
\begin{align*}
z_H=\begin{cases}
0,&\mbox{if }1\leq t<2(1/\alpha-1),\\
\frac{t[\alpha(2t^2+1)-1-\sqrt{(1-\alpha)[\alpha( 8t^3-4t^2-3)+1]+t\alpha^2}]}{\alpha(4t^3-1)},&\mbox{if }t\geq \max\{2(1/\alpha-1),1\},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
And $z_L=z_H/t$.
I numerically observe that $z_H$ is always increasing in $t$. And $z_L$ is unimodal in $t$ for $\alpha\leq 4/5$ but is decreasing in $t$ for $\alpha\in[4/5,1]$. How to prove this property? It is difficult to directly take derivatives, I've tried. I also checked that $f$ is not a supermodular function, i.e., $\partial^2 f(z,t)/\partial t\partial z $ is not always positive. Hence, we cannot use the Topiks theorem. I also tried "single crossing property", but it is hard to prove $f$ satisfies this property.
So far, all I can prove is: when $\alpha<4/5$, $z_L$ is non-monotone in $t$. First, it is obvious that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}z_L(t)=0$. Second, for $\alpha\in[2/3,1]$, $z_L=\frac{ \alpha(2t^2+1)-1-\sqrt{(1-\alpha)[\alpha( 8t^3-4t^2-3)+1]+t\alpha^2}}{\alpha(4t^3-1)}$, one can verify that at $t=1$, we have $\frac{dz_L(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=1}=\frac{15\alpha^2-32\alpha+16}{6\alpha}>0\Leftrightarrow\alpha<4/5$. For $\alpha\in[0,2/3)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{dz_L(t)}{dt}\bigg|_{t=2(1/\alpha-1)}>0\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}
9\alpha^2-17\alpha+8> 0,\\
J_1(\alpha)\triangleq 32- 33\alpha^3 + 96\alpha^2 - 96\alpha> 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Note that $J''_1(\alpha)=192-198\alpha>0,~\forall~\alpha\in[0,2/3]$, which implies $J'_1(\alpha)$ is increasing in $\alpha\in[0,2/3]$ and we have $J_1'(2/3)=-12<0$ implying $J_1(\alpha)$ is decreasing in $\alpha\in[0,2/3]$ with $J_1(2/3)=8/9>0$.
But this is still far from the final goal. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

In this answer, we prove that $z_L(t)$ is unimodal, given $0 < \alpha < \frac45$.
Let
$$f(t) := \frac{\alpha(2t^2+1)-1-\sqrt{(1-\alpha)[\alpha( 8t^3-4t^2-3)+1]+t\alpha^2}}{\alpha(4t^3-1)}.$$
It suffices to prove that $f(t)$ is unimodal on $t \ge 1$, given $0 < \alpha < \frac45$.
It suffices to prove that $f'(t) = 0$ has exactly one real solution on $[1, \infty)$. Let $g(t) := t^2 \cdot f'(t)$.
(Note: This is a trick. We hope to find $h(t) > 0$ such that
$h(t)f'(t)$ is strictly decreasing. $h(t) = t^2$ works.)
It suffices to prove that $g(t) = 0$ has exactly one real solution on $[1, \infty)$.
Note that
$g(1) = \frac{(5a-4)(3a-4)}{6a} > 0$,
and $\lim_{t\to \infty} g(t) = -\frac12 < 0$. It suffices to prove that $g'(t) < 0$ on $(1, \infty)$. After some manipulation, it suffices to prove that, for all $0 < \alpha < \frac45$ and $t \ge 1$,
$$F(t)\cdot Q(t) + G(t) > 0 \tag{1}$$
where $Q(t) := \sqrt{(1-\alpha)[\alpha( 8t^3-4t^2-3)+1]+t\alpha^2}$, and
\begin{align*}
 F(t) &:= 3072\,{a}^{3}{t}^{8}+1536\,{a}^{3}{t}^{7}-6144\,{a}^{2}{t}^{8}-1920\,{
  a}^{3}{t}^{6}+3072\,a{t}^{8}\\
 &\qquad +1920\,{a}^{2}{t}^{6}-1536\,a{t}^{7}-1536
 \,{a}^{3}{t}^{4}-384\,{a}^{2}{t}^{5}-384\,{a}^{3}{t}^{3}\\
 &\qquad +2688\,{a}^{2}
 {t}^{4}-384\,a{t}^{5}-624\,{a}^{3}{t}^{2}+384\,{a}^{2}{t}^{3}-1152\,a{
  t}^{4}\\
 &\qquad +384\,{t}^{5}-144\,{a}^{3}t+1344\,{a}^{2}{t}^{2}+192\,t{a}^{2}-
 960\,a{t}^{2}-48\,at+192\,{t}^{2},\\
 G(t) &:= 3072\,{a}^{4}{t}^{11}-6144\,{a}^{4}{t}^{10}-6144\,{a}^{3}{t}^{11}-768
 \,{a}^{4}{t}^{9}+12288\,{a}^{3}{t}^{10}\\
 &\qquad +3072\,{a}^{2}{t}^{11}+1536\,{a
 }^{4}{t}^{8}-1280\,{a}^{3}{t}^{9}-6144\,{a}^{2}{t}^{10}-6672\,{a}^{4}{
  t}^{7}\\
 &\qquad +3072\,{a}^{3}{t}^{8}+2048\,{a}^{2}{t}^{9}+2304\,{a}^{4}{t}^{6}+
 11520\,{a}^{3}{t}^{7}-9216\,{a}^{2}{t}^{8}\\
 &\qquad -1920\,{a}^{4}{t}^{5}-6528\,
 {a}^{3}{t}^{6}-2304\,{a}^{2}{t}^{7}+4608\,a{t}^{8}+4056\,{a}^{4}{t}^{4
 }\\
&\qquad +5952\,{a}^{3}{t}^{5}+4224\,{a}^{2}{t}^{6}-2304\,a{t}^{7}+1152\,{a}^{
  4}{t}^{3}-9216\,{a}^{3}{t}^{4}\\
 &\qquad -4032\,{a}^{2}{t}^{5}+1200\,{a}^{4}{t}^{
  2}-1680\,{a}^{3}{t}^{3}+6912\,{a}^{2}{t}^{4}-384\,a{t}^{5} +147\,{a}^{4
 }t\\
 &\qquad -3312\,{a}^{3}{t}^{2}+528\,{a}^{2}{t}^{3}-1536\,a{t}^{4}+384\,{t}^{5
 }+12\,{a}^{4} -336\,{a}^{3}t\\
&\qquad +3264\,{a}^{2}{t}^{2}-16\,{a}^{3}+240\,t{a}
 ^{2}-1344\,a{t}^{2}+4\,{a}^{2}-48\,at+192\,{t}^{2}. 
\end{align*}
(1) is true which is verified by Mathematica - a Computer Algebra System (CAS). The Mathematica code is given below:
f[a_, t_, Q_] := ......  (note: long; it is $F(t)\cdot Q + G(t)$)
pos1 := a > 0 && a < 4/5 && t >= 1 &&
Q^2 == (1 - a)(a(8t^3 - 4t^2 - 3) + 1) + t*a^2 && Q >= 0
Resolve[ForAll[{a, t, Q}, pos1, f[a, t, Q] > 0], Reals]
We can prove (1) using the Buffalo Way (BW).
Let $a = \frac45\cdot \frac{1}{1 + u}$ and $t = 1 + v$ for $u > 0, v \ge 0$.
Then $G(t) = \frac{64}{625(1+u)^4}G_1(u, v)$ where $G_1(u, v)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients and positive constant term. Thus, $G(t) > 0$ on $t \ge 1$. Thus, we only need to prove the case $F(t) \le 0$. Using $Q(t)
\le \frac{1 + [Q(t)]^2}{2}$, it suffices to prove that
$$F(t) \cdot \frac{1 + [Q(t)]^2}{2} + G(t) > 0$$
or
$$\frac{64}{3125(1+u)^5}M(u, v) > 0$$
where $M(u, v)$ is a polynomial with non-negative coefficients and positive constant term. Thus, the desired inequality is true.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
